# Automapper flattening issues

Tags: automapper, flatten

I am new to Automapper so this is probably a simple solution, but I am having trouble flattening objects. For example I have the following db call:

```
var le = db.LeagueEvents.Include("Venue").Include(p => p.venue.place).ToList();
```

Here is what `LeagueEvents`, `Venue` and `Place` look like:

```
public class LeagueEvent
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }
    public Venue venue { get; set; }
}

public class Venue
{
    public string VenueName { get; set; }
    public Place place { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    public string address { get; set;}
}
```

Now when I do a straight conversion to a VM of `DailyEvent` it maps out fine

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<LeagueEvent, LeagueEventViewModelDailies>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Place, PlaceViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Venue, VenueViewModelDailies>();
```

But when I try to flatten it out using a vm like:

```
 public class DailyEventVM
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }
    public string VenueName { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

I return nulls for `VenueName` and `address`

Do I need to do something like:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.VenueName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Venue.VenueName)
```

If so is there a "bulk" way of doing this because I could see it getting quite complicated with a large number of fields to be mapped.

**UPDATE**
I am beginning to think it might have something to do with EF and proxy objects.
Because the following works:

```
            Mapper.CreateMap<LeagueEvent, LeagueEventViewModelDailies>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Address, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.place.Address))
            .ForMember(d => d.AptUnit, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.place.AptUnit))
            .ForMember(d => d.City, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.place.City))
            .ForMember(d => d.State, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.place.State))
            .ForMember(d => d.PostalCode, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.place.PostalCode))
            .ForMember(d => d.Latitude, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.place.Latitude))
            .ForMember(d => d.Longitude, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.place.Longitude))
            .ForMember(d => d.VenueName, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.VenueName))
            .ForMember(d => d.VenueDescription, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.Description))
            .ForMember(d => d.PrimaryPhone, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.PrimaryPhone))
            .ForMember(d => d.SecondaryPhone, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.SecondaryPhone))
            .ForMember(d => d.Link, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.venue.Link));
```

And these work (independently of each other):

```
lvm = Mapper.Map<Venue, LeagueEventViewModelDailies>(l.venue);
            lvm = Mapper.Map<Place, LeagueEventViewModelDailies>(l.venue.place);
```

using each of the above independently they return the venue information or the place information correctly.

However, the following still returns a null for place and venue:

```
lvm = Mapper.Map<LeagueEvent, LeagueEventViewModelDailies>(l);
```

When I drill in and look at "l" venue and place are proxy objects and I think that is what is causing the nulls.

The first example was a subset of what I am working with for brevity.

As always thanks for the help,

Comment: I don't have time to construct an example right now, but take a look at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening . 'If for any property on the destination type a property, method, or a method prefixed with "Get" does not exist on the source type, AutoMapper splits the destination member name into individual words (by PascalCase conventions).'

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I did look at that before posting and with some further testing what is happening is the Venue object isn't being mapped but the Place object is. For the time being I went ahead and used the formember method and it is working now but I would really like to understand  why venue isnt mapping out fully.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the Venue Name isn't mapped is that it's not named consistently. In your target class, it's called `VenueName`, which automapper will pick up as `(src).Venue.Name`, but in the `Venue` class, the member is called `VenueName`.

Your Options:

1. Rename `Venue.VenueName` to `Venue.Name`
2. Rename `DailyEventVM.VenueName` to `DailyEventVM.VenueVenueName`

Using that same logic, the address property should be called `DailyEventVM.VenuePlaceAddress`, which Automapper will split on pascal case to be `(src).Venue.Place.Address`

Answer (score 0):

You can map several source objects  to one destination object (like yours VM object), it's much easier to configure:

```
public class Src1
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
}

public class Src2
{
    public string P2 { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    public string P2 { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Src1, Dest>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Src2, Dest>();

var src1 = new Src1 { P1 = "foo" };
var src2 = new Src2 { P2 = "bar" };
var dest = new Dest();

Mapper.Map(src1, dest);
Mapper.Map(src2, dest);

Assert.AreEqual("foo", dest.P1);
Assert.AreEqual("bar", dest.P2);
```